# change access control for diffrent roles

Tags: php, symfony, security, yaml, access-control

A role Called ROLE_EDUCATOR cant seem to get files from a folder called uploads.

i tried to change the symfony security file where you can change level of access.

This is the role role hierarchy set in the file

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_LOCATION_MANAGER: [ROLE_EDUCATOR]
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_LOCATION_MANAGER]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN]
```

what needs to change is the uploads/avatars path where avatars/foto's are pulled from

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/uploads/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/uploads/avatars, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

the result i got from loging in as a user with roles higher than ROLE_EDUCATOR is that i could see the images load but as i log in as educator role the image becomes the a image like the ones you see where the src is not linked good

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/uploads/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/uploads/avatars, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

so just change the role to `roles`

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html